# How do I use CreateObjectSet<TEntity> where TEntity as a parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am looking for a way to pass Entity and TEntity as a parameter so that I can use this method as a generic method. Something like that :

```
    private void AttachSingleEntity(Entity singleEntity, TEntity Tentity)
    {       
        ObjectSet<Tentity> objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<Tentity>();
        objectSet.Attach(singleEntity);
    }
```

Then I call AttachSingleEntity as below :

```
    customer cus = new customer {id = 1};
    AttachSingleEntity(cus,customer);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change to

```
private void AttachSingleEntity<TEntity>(Entity singleEntity) where TEntity:class
{       
    ObjectSet<TEntity> objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    objectSet.Attach(singleEntity);
}
```

Comment: It shows error: "The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TEntity>"

Comment: @JatSing then add a class contraint. I edited my answer for that. And i just noticed that the second parameter isnt necessary, of course.